# Error handling not quite working as expected

Tags: c#, error-handling, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm still trying to master front-end development with ASP.NET Core 5 MVC - and I'm still struggling with some issues regarding error handling.

I have defined a number of roles for my app - and I use those as `[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]` annotation on some of my Razor pages (their "code-behind" PageModel class):

```
[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
public class MyCustomPageModel : PageModel
{
    // page model code
}
```

I then also created a Razor page `AccessDenied.cshtml` in the `Error` folder:

[image]

My expectation would now be: if the user isn't authorized, or not member of that specified role, then ASP.NET Core would throw an error (http 401 - unauthorized) and go to my error page and display it.

Unfortunately - that's not what happens - instead, I get an error:

> HTTP ERROR 404
> No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:44332/Account/AccessDenied?ReturnUrl=%2FMyCustomMethod

I don't understand where that `Account/` is coming from - I never defined it anywhere (to my - albeit limited - knowledge).

I also tried to specifically instruct the runtime to use the `/Error` pages for error handling by doing this in the `Startup.Configure` method (for the `env.IsDevelopment()` branch):

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            // app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }
```

but that didn't change anything.....

So - what am I missing? Where's that `Account/` coming from - and how can I influence this?? (e.g. replace `/Account/AccessDenied` with `/Error/AccessDenied`)

**Update:** I created this app with the "Microsoft Identity Platform" auth type option; I'm using OpenID Connect with JWT Bearer Tokens.

This is my set up in `Startup` class - `ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
         .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
            
services.AddAuthorization();
```

Comment: When you use the 'normal' Identity from MS then you should have an Areas/Identity folder. The /Account/* is part of that, canned in a DLL.  Use Scaffolding to add its code to your Project.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: thanks - I used ASP.NET Core web app, with Razor pages, and with MS Identity as my auth scheme - but I have nothing like an `Areas/Identity` folder or anything like this

Comment: Did you use the starter template or did you add packages to an 'empty web app' ?  Scaffolding might still work, try it in  a scratch project.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: I just used the default templates that come with VS 2019

Comment: The std template has a Authentication combobox, what was that showing?

Comment: @HenkHolterman: "Microsoft Identity Platform" - and when I configured it, I got to pick an Azure app registration, and it set up the whole OpenID Connect config and code

Comment: In that case I think you ran into an 'unfinished' corner of this Identiy maze. The /Account/* pages are part of the "Individual Accounts" pattern.

Comment: If you have found a solution, please post it in the answer space below. Solutions do not belong in questions but in answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using an application cookie as your authentication scheme (rather than e.g. JWT/bearer tokens). If not, please share your `Startup.ConfigureServices` to show how you set up Identity.

If I'm correct, you should be able to configure the path that the application should redirect to in case of an HTTP status code 403 Forbidden response. 401 Unauthorized is typically when the user is not authorized at all (not logged in) as opposed to "just" not having the proper role.

To configure the path, if you don't want the standard `/Account/AccessDenied`, adding the following in your `Startup.ConfigureServices` should work:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Error/AccessDenied";
});
```

For more info on configuring this cookie (and other Identity configuration) take a look at the [Identity documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?view=aspnetcore-5.0#cookie-settings).

Comment: I've shared my auth setup - I'm using OpenID Connect, which I believe does use JWT bearer tokens (returns an ID token).

Comment: I tried adding that `ConfigureApplicationCookie`  call to my Startup/ConfigureServices method, but the error stays the same, I don't see any change/improvement...

Comment: You were *really close* - see my updated question - somehow, I just had to use that statement I found somewhere (rather than yours) to actually make it work. Thanks for your answer, though ! You sent me searching in the right direction. Accepted.

Comment: @marc_s good to hear it! It does, however, seem that you can also configure it as part of [AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.web.microsoftidentitywebappauthenticationbuilderextensions.addmicrosoftidentitywebapp?view=azure-dotnet-preview) (the last overload takes CookieAuthenticationOptions). Should give you the same result anyway.